# how to read tags associated to AWS Lambda function?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to read the tags associated to AWS lambda function using boto3 API with python

```
    import boto3
    client = boto3.client('lambda')
    response = client.list_tags(Resource=arn)
```

when I test the above code from lambda function , i see network API error.Is there any way to read the tags from context ? I appreciate your help.

Comment: Could you please provide the error?

Comment: I'm just seeing network API error on top of lambda function, even I couldn't find anything from cloudwatch

Comment: Could you please provide the error? Also, can you do anything else with the api? Do you have your credentials set up correctly?

Answer (score 0):

set your client variable as:

```html
client  = boto3.client('lambda', 
                      aws_access_key_id=Awscred.aws_access_key_id,                                  
                      aws_secret_access_key=Awscred.aws_secret_access_key,
                      region_name=Awscred.region_name)
```

this worked for me